# Custom ListView scrolling repeat data

Tags: android, listview

I'm going through a rather annoying problem. I have visited many questions solution to this same problem in the forum but can not get work for me. I'm loading a ListView with an adapter that I created. The data that I show are from my database. Each cell in the list has a button to click, call a function to edit a field in the database that record. When ready records in this listView is fine, but as I get down the listview, certain data begin to change. At one point, I evaluate if my item is validated or not (is a field of the database which can be a 0 or a 1 in the event that this validated). If it is validated, that button will load a background as an image and annul that denuevo click on it. If the value was validated 0, I created a click event for this button. Then, when I go down the listView picture button begins to change, even while under and climb changing all but the difference is that in them if I can click. I do not understand because they change the images, when I am validating before a registry value is in a predetermined value. I'll let my code.

My class adapter

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<RowItem> items;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtNombre;
    TextView txtTicket;
    TextView txtAsiento;
    TextView txtOrden;
    TextView txtNumero;
    TextView txtMensaje;
    TextView txtAdicionales;
    TextView txtOtros;
    TextView txtCategoria;
    Button btn;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public RowItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtNombre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        holder.txtAsiento = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAsiento);
        holder.txtTicket = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTicket);
        holder.txtNumero = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumero);
        holder.txtOrden = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOrden);
        holder.txtAdicionales = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAdicionales);
        holder.txtOtros = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOtros);
        holder.txtCategoria = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoria);
        holder.btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.txtMensaje = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else{
        //Whenever recycling Holder, the elements begin to change in  the values that I mentioned.
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    String codigoEvento = manager.getValue(parent.getContext(), "codigoEvento");
    holder.txtOrden.setText(Html.fromHtml("Orden de compra: <b>"+codigoEvento+"-"+rowItem.getId_inscripcion()+"</b>"));
    if (!rowItem.getAsiento().equals("") && !rowItem.getAsiento().equals("null") && rowItem.getAsiento() != null) {
        holder.txtAsiento.setText(Html.fromHtml("Asiento: <b>"+rowItem.getAsiento()+"</b>"));
        holder.txtAsiento.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (!rowItem.getNumero().equals("") && !rowItem.getNumero().equals("null") && rowItem.getNumero() != null) {
        holder.txtNumero.setText(Html.fromHtml("Número: <b>"+rowItem.getNumero()+"</b>"));
        holder.txtNumero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (!rowItem.getAdicionales().equals("") && !rowItem.getAdicionales().equals("null") && rowItem.getAdicionales() != null) {
        holder.txtAdicionales.setText(Html.fromHtml("Adicionales: <b>"+rowItem.getAdicionales()+"</b>"));
        holder.txtAdicionales.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (!rowItem.getOtros().equals("") && !rowItem.getOtros().equals("null") && rowItem.getOtros() != null) {
        holder.txtOtros.setText(Html.fromHtml("Otros: <b>"+rowItem.getOtros()+"</b>"));
        holder.txtOtros.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(rowItem.getCategoria() != null){
        if (!rowItem.getCategoria().equals("") && !rowItem.getCategoria().equals("null") && rowItem.getCategoria() != null || !rowItem.getCategoria().isEmpty()) {
            holder.txtCategoria.setText(Html.fromHtml("Categoría: <b>"+rowItem.getCategoria()+"</b>"));
            holder.txtCategoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    //Adicionales y otros
    if(rowItem.getValidado()==1){
            holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_alert);
            holder.btn.setText("");
            holder.txtMensaje.setText("E-ticket ya validado");
            holder.txtMensaje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.width = 50;
            params.height = 50;
            params.rightMargin = 63;
            params.topMargin = 10;
            params.bottomMargin = 5;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    }else{
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
                RowItem item_click = getItem(position);
                Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                TextView t=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
                t.setText("E-ticket validado");
                Activity activity = (Activity)CustomListViewAdapter.this.getContext();
                TextView ts = (TextView)(activity.findViewById(R.id.txtDisponibles));
                t.setText("E-ticket validado");
                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_check);
                b.setText("");
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.width = 50;
                params.height = 50;
                params.rightMargin = 63;
                params.topMargin = 10;
                params.bottomMargin = 5;
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                b.setLayoutParams(params);
                SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
                BaseDeDatos nueva = new BaseDeDatos();
                nueva.validarMultiple(activity, item_click);
                int validadas = manager.getValueInt(parent.getContext(), "validadas");
                int totales = manager.getValueInt(parent.getContext(), "totales");
                if(validadas > 0){
                    validadas = validadas - 1;
                    manager.setValueInt(parent.getContext(), "validadas", validadas);
                    manager.setValueInt(parent.getContext(), "totales", totales);
                    ts.setText(validadas+"/"+totales);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    return convertView;
   }
}
```

Layout list :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAdicionales"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumero"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOtros"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAdicionales"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCategoria"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtOtros"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green_small"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:text="Validar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="SDSDSDS"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set your holder setting data code inside else block of convertView

Comment: be more specific? You say todos los setting in the block else?

Comment: yes setText methods inside else block

Comment: That does not work for me, so does every time scroll applies data are repeated.

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong? @VivekMishra

Comment: That was the case with me when I had this problem

Comment: But could write the code to see how it should be? Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of view recycling. When adapter need to show a new element in your list has two possibilities:

1. Create a new element: this element has the default values of your layout.
2. Reuse an element that is not longer visible: this element has the old    value.

For this reason, you need to put the right values to your list element inside of getView. You are not doing this with your button, if `rowItem.getValidado()!=1` you set the `OnClickListener` to your button but you are not changed the background for the right one.

You can add a field inside of `RowItem` to save the state and restore the state of the fields inside of `getView`. Something like this:

```
 if(rowItem.getClicked()){
     holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_check);
     holder.btn.setOnClickListener(null);
}else if(rowItem.getValidado()==1){
            holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_alert);
            holder.btn.setText("");
            holder.txtMensaje.setText("E-ticket ya validado");
            holder.txtMensaje.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.width = 50;
            params.height = 50;
            params.rightMargin = 63;
            params.topMargin = 10;
            params.bottomMargin = 5;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            holder.btn.setLayoutParams(params);

            holder.btn.setOnClickListener(null);
    }else{
        holder.btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_green_small);

        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               rowItem.setClicked(true);

                RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
                RowItem item_click = getItem(position);
                Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                TextView t=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
                t.setText("E-ticket validado");
                Activity activity = (Activity)CustomListViewAdapter.this.getContext();
                TextView ts = (TextView)(activity.findViewById(R.id.txtDisponibles));
                t.setText("E-ticket validado");
                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_check);
                b.setText("");
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.width = 50;
                params.height = 50;
                params.rightMargin = 63;
                params.topMargin = 10;
                params.bottomMargin = 5;
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                b.setLayoutParams(params);
                SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
                BaseDeDatos nueva = new BaseDeDatos();
                nueva.validarMultiple(activity, item_click);
                int validadas = manager.getValueInt(parent.getContext(), "validadas");
                int totales = manager.getValueInt(parent.getContext(), "totales");
                if(validadas > 0){
                    validadas = validadas - 1;
                    manager.setValueInt(parent.getContext(), "validadas", validadas);
                    manager.setValueInt(parent.getContext(), "totales", totales);
                    ts.setText(validadas+"/"+totales);
                }
            }
        });
        }
```

Comment: Just try the code and does not work well: / could put more of my example code to see well where to put that if?